# haproxy setup is not working when resource utilization become high

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

We are using HA proxy v2.3 in our organization for load balancing our apache application servers. Three web application servers are configured in haproxy. 
When any one of the web application server resource utilization become high then the load balancing will not work. All the web requests will occupy in that high load server.Then the incoming requests will not equally distribute to other servers. So we will not able to access the web page.So at that time we have to edit the haproxy.cfg file and have to comment the high resource utilized server and will reload the haproxy service. Then only the application become up.

Is there any option in haproxy.cfg file to overcome this situation?

If the server load become high then that node have to skip and the request should pass to other nodes.

The configuration is as follows:-

global

```
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    maxpipes 1024
    nogetaddrinfo
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!     MD5!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!PSK
```

defaults

```
    log global
    mode    http
    retries 3
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close

    stats enable
    stats auth arun:arun@123
    stats uri /haproxy
    timeout server 1200s
    timeout connect 20s
    timeout client 60s
    log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 notice
    default-server rise 1
     default-server fall 20
```

frontend app_nodes

```
    bind *:443 ssl crt <Certificate file>  no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend Application-nodes
```

backend Application-nodes

```
    balance roundrobin
    server <server name> <IP>:80 weight 1 maxconn 2500 check
    server <server name> <IP>:80 weight 1 maxconn 2500 check
    server <server name> <IP>:80 weight 1 maxconn 2500 check
    log 127.0.0.1:514 local3 alert
    log 127.0.0.1:514 local2 info
```

Comment: Please suggest how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please show your backend configuration section.  If you have configured health checks, HAProxy should automatically stop sending traffic to the unhealthy target.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot   global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        maxpipes 1024
        nogetaddrinfo
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!PSK

Comment: Please edit this into the question.  The config is very difficult to read in the comments section.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added

Comment: Hi please anyone provide a solution for this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot please check and update it.